# Multiple triggers on a single interruption on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, interrupt, isr

I am working on Arduinos and I would like to use interrupts to use a *rotary encoder*. But I would like to reduce the interrupt code to the minimum.

Can I use multiple triggers on a single interrupt?

I would like to replcace my actual code :

```
attachInterrupt(0, ChangeA, CHANGE);
```

To something like

```
attachInterrupt(0, FailingA, FAILING);
attachInterrupt(0, RisingA, RISING);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Is the rotary encoder used by you (i.e. it is an input peripheral, like a knob) or by a motor? And consequently.. What is the maximum frequency you get at the pins? And... here is the last and most important question: do you REALLY need this code to be implemented in an interrupt? Is it so fast and important that you need an interrupt to handle it? If the frequency is less than.. let's say 100 Hz, probably it is better to handle it in software (polling)...

Comment: Hmmm... I'm sorry but I have 2 rotary encoders ... with 1024 tics each. It means with two rotation per seconds (40cm/s) i have got 8000 interruptions... 8kHz is too much to handle it in software! (This is not the only thing I have to do on this Arduino).

Answer (score 1):

No, not exactly possible. The external interrupt is configured to react only to one of the possibilities internally.

One thing you can do is to use a `CHANGE` interrupt service routine and test the value of the pin at the beginning of the ISR to do `FallingA()` or `RisingA()`.

There is a potential problem here. The pin may have changed again before you test it, so the interrupt that triggered the interrupt could have been falling, say, and your test determines that it was rising. One way to guard against two quick interrupts is to check if the flag is still set. It should have been cleared if at the start of the interrupt, and if it is set then a change happened again. There is no practical way to guard against three quick changes.

If you really want to use two separate ISRs, do you have an extra pin available? If so, you could just wire the pins together and run a `FALLING` ISR on one and a `RISING` ISR on the other.

Comment: That's what I thought. Damnit! I have 2 rotary encoder and 2 of the interrupt pins are used by I2C. Thanks anyway! (: